# Hibernate Unexpected gap in ordinal parameter

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, pagination

I have got an Springboot App with mysql The code is as follows:

```
public interface IHouseDao extends JpaRepository <House, String>{

@Query(value ="SELECT H.*, ( 4 ) AS distance FROM house H"
        , nativeQuery = true)
Page<House> search(Pageable pageable);
}
```

that code throws the following error

> Unknown column 'H' in 'field list'

But if I change

```
search(Pageable pageable)
```

to

```
search()
```

then the query works fine.

I need the query to be pageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you have here is selecting all columns from the `house` table and then you are adding `distance` column with the value of `4`, The `H.*` part of the query shows that all the house column should be returned, but in your `house` there is no such thing column named `H`

you need to use named parameters in your native query instead of positional parameters

```
public interface IHouseDao extends JpaRepository<House, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT H.*, ( 4 ) AS distance FROM house H",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM house H",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<House> search(Pageable pageable);
}
```

this snippet uses named parameters

I have added a `countQuery` parameter to the `@Query` and this separate query that returns total number of records that match the search.

I removed the parameter you had which is `4` and replaced it with hard coded value, you change the value and put on parameters so you can pass them through your query

Comment: Yes, it was there